Could we have a series of $1/2-1/4-1/8-1/16-\ldots $ converge?
Could we have a series of $1/2-1/4-1/8-1/16-\ldots $ converge?
I think it this series would not exist because there is not such a thing can make the first term positive and rest of them negative

You might be thinking that a series "should" be defined by a simple algebraic rule, like $\sum 2^{-n}$ or $\sum (-2)^{-n}$. But not every infinite series is like that. It's perfectly valid to talk about the series in your question. (And in fact, it does converge.)

What does it then converge to?

Compute the first few terms and see if you get an idea.  Alternately, note that after the first term you have a geometric series.  Sum that and add the $\frac 12$ at the end.
